# Knowledge graph API returning different results than site

Tags: api, search, google-api, google-knowledge-graph

When I Google for something and click on a heading from the Knowledge Graph, Google displays a list of the results just below the search bar:
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHP80.png)

I typed in the same thing in my Knowledge Graph API:

> https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=apple%20products&key=[MY_KEY]&indent=True&limit=100

and the results are not the same. Short of scraping, is there a way of obtaining the exact list shown within the results via a Google API? It doesn't seem to be Knowledge Graph, or at least the queries are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

> Short of scraping, is there a way of obtaining the exact list shown
>   within the results via a Google API? It doesn't seem to be Knowledge
>   Graph

Apparently not, you are using the correct API but unfortunately that is how the API works—it usually gives you a different result than if you do a simple Google search.

Why this is the case—I don't know. I decided scrape google instead.

Answer (score 1):

The Knowledge Graph API doesn't have access to the same data sources as a simple Google search. You can read about here if interested (https://web.archive.org/web/20130329151128/http://zecblog.com/2012/09/16/the-short-life-of-the-open-knowledge-graph/).

But yes in short, you'll have to do your own scraping if you want the same information, although it's difficult because Google purposely obfuscates the HTML tags.